# How to calculate pole strength for this magnet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I know magnetic mono poles don't exists and a magnetic poles always have equal strength. But what about a magnet which looks like this?
[image]
This is picture of magnet whose thickness is constantly decreasing
Will it have poles of unlike strength or such magnets cant exist?

Answer (score 0):

A magnet consists of subatomic particles with aligned magnetic dipoles. More precisely, with more or less aligned dipoles, which together form a macroscopic magnetic field.

Faraday introduced the lines of force and modeling a magnet with such lines of forces is a good way to understand what is happening. First at all the poles of a magnet are a simplification. In reality the loops of the lines of forces are going through the subatomic particles and left the magnet not necessarily at the plane ends. Instead of your example the shape of a magnet could be formed as a rhombus and the lines of forces will leave the magnet to the left and to the right.

[image] . [image]

In the second picture you can see that even with a bar magnet, the magnetic field does not only leave the magnet at the plane ends.

Answer (score 0):

The magnet you drew can exist. If the material has a constant magnetization, then the pole strength of an end is proportional to the area of the end.